# New app limit for google playstore app name max lenght character to 30?

Tags: android, google-play-console

So a year ago the limit of the app name was 50 characters, now the limit is 30. Is this for real? Why I can still see some apps with app names grater than 30 characters?

Comment: `Is this for real?` impossible for us to answer here, find the policies regarding the store for answers, `Why I can still see some apps with app names grater than 30 characters?` again, impossible to answer, you'll have to review the policies of the store yourself

Comment: it only applies from July 2022, I'm guessing the end of July as it didn't give a specific date

Answer (score 4):

Yes...

As per the new policies from July 2022, Google Play will truncate titles that violate the new 30-character limit.
Check your app titles (and translations) and reduce any that are still longer than 30 characters.

Follow these steps to rename your app:

1. Log in to your Google Play Console.
2. Select the app among the list that you want to rename.
3. Now you will see the dashboard of that particular app.
4. Go to Store Presense section in left pane of menu.
5. Go to Main Store listing.
6. Scroll down the page. Here, you can see the App details section, where you can rename the app as per the new policies.